Find all function such that for all real $x,y$, $f(x+f(y))=y+f(x)$
I already get some useful information, such that

$f(f(x))=x$, so $f(x)$ bijective.
$f(x)+f(-x)=0$
$f(kf(x))=kf(x)$ for all $k$ integer.
Then, I got stuck.
Can anyone help me ???


As currently stated, (3) is wrong.  Can you show the arguments for each of (1)-(3)?

Defining the relation $P(x,y): f(x+f(y))=y+f(x)$, How about looking at $P(x,f(y))$?

Try using sub-vector space of a $\Bbb{Q}$ -vector space $\Bbb{R}$.

@HackR thank you for your idea. You will get a cauchy functions :) I think I should do FEq more again :v

Would you accept if I wrote the hint as an answer? Just to get the question off the unanswered list?

@HackR I want to ask, the Cauchy Functions just true for real to real if $f(x)$ is monotone, differentiable, or continuous. But the problem is for all $x,y$ real. How you prove its monotone, differentiable, or continous ?

It is not that simple without anymore assumptions. There are a lot of different solutions. See Mohsen Shahriari's comment in this answer.
